# Get the date after six months from a specific date and count how many days have passed since that day in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the employees that have worked for more then 6 months and how many days have passed since that day.

I've fetched the employees with six months experience using the following query:

```
$empsWithSixMonthsExp = Employees::whereDate('joining_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->where('status', 1)->get();
```

But now I want to **get the date when their 6 month was fulfilled** and **how many days** have **passed** **since** **completing  their  6 month mark**.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know below solution is working or not for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example for single record

```
$joiningDate = '05/06/2021';
$AfterSixMonthDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', 
  $joiningDate)->addMonths(6);
$todaysDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$daysDifferent = $todaysDate->diff( $AfterSixMonthDate)->format('%a Days');
```

you can dump this code

```
  dd( $daysDifferent,$AfterSixMonthDate,\Carbon\Carbon::now());
```